# How to create K8S deployment in specific namespace?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I am using `kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/controllers/nginx-deployment.yaml` to create deployment.

I want to create deployment in my namespace `examplenamespace`.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

By adding `-n namespace` to command you already have. It also works with other types of resources.

```
kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/controllers/nginx-deployment.yaml -n namespacename
```

Answer (score 42):

There are three possible solutions.

1. Specify namespace in the `kubectl` `apply` or `create` command:

```
kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/controllers/nginx-deployment.yaml -n my-namespace
```

2. Specify namespace in your `yaml` files:

```
  apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    name: my-deployment
    namespace: my-namespace
```

3. Change default namespace in `~/.kube/config`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Config
clusters:
- name: "k8s-dev-cluster-01"
  cluster:
    server: "https://example.com/k8s/clusters/abc"
    namespace: "my-namespace"
```

Answer (score 2):

First you need to create the namespace likes this

```sh
kubectl create ns nameOfYourNamespace
```

Then you create your deployment under your namespace

```sh
kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/controllers/nginx-deployment.yaml -n examplenamespace
```

---

The ns at

```sh
kubectl create ns nameOfYourNamespace
```

stands for namespace

The -n

```sh
kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/controllers/nginx-deployment.yaml -n examplenamespace
```

stands for --namespace

---

So you first create your namespace in order Kubernetes know what namespaces dealing with.

Then when you are about to apply your changes you add the -n flag that stands for --namespace so Kubernetes know under what namespace will deploy/ create the proper resources